# how can i share function of one sibling to another sibling component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

here i know how to get the data from a json but i found difficult while retrieving the data form a json based on an id that reference another json the problem statement is here i have a json of api/users contains 10 users and each have 10 blogs there is also an api  for api/posts which contains all the posts now i have to retrieve the data like when i click on user1 the blogs related to userid 1 have to be shown

this is service.ts

```
getUsers(): Observable<UserModel[]> {
return this.http.get<UserModel[]>(`${this._url}/users`)}

getUserBlogPosts(userId:number){
return this.http.get<BlogsModel[]>(`${this._url}/posts?userId=${userId}`)}
```

user.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.getUsersOnSubscribe()  }
getUsersOnSubscribe(){
this.service.getUsers().subscribe(
  data =>{
    console.log(data);
    this.users = data;
  } 
)}
 onClickUser(users){  
this.currentUser = users
let id = users.id
console.log(id)        
this.service.getUserBlogPosts(id).subscribe(
  data=>{
    console.log(data)
    this.currentUser = data
  })  }
```

.blog.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.getBlogsList();  }

 getBlogsList() {
let id  = this.blog
this.service.getUserBlogPosts(id.userId).subscribe(
  data=>{
    console.log(data)
    this.blogs=data;
  }
)}
```

}

i am able to filter the data here in user component when i click on onclick(users) in console, i want this output to be shown in blogs component how to do that & Also having a problem after getting the blogs of user1 on click it is redirecting to url/posts?userId=1 and when i try editing the url to url/posts?userId=2 it is not showing any data. How to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can reuse your service and emit the data from a behaviorSubject

Service.ts

```
constructor() {
   this._currentUser = new BehaviorSubject(null);
   this.currentUser$ = this._currentUser.asObservable();
}

setCurrentUser(user) {
   this._currentUser.next(user);
}
```

user.ts

```
this.service.getUserBlogPosts(id).subscribe(
  data=>{
    this.currentUser = data
    // Emits your value
    this.service.setCurrentUser(this.currentUser)
  } 
)
```

blog.ts

```
this.service.currentUser.subscribe(
    user => {
       //The data you emitted from user.ts is available here, do your logic
    }
)
```

Comment: Also having a problem after getting the blogs of user1 on click it is redirecting to url/posts?userId=1 and when i try editing the url to url/posts?userId=2 it is not showing any data. How to resolve this

Comment: Please create a new question describing your problem